# asp.net ajax calls to user controls

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

When calling page methods or web services with either jquery or MSAjax, the Session object appears to be null so Im finding it hard to track users who execute them.

Seeing that the session id is sent with the cookie on each request, is it possible to obtain the session object from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the session in your WebMethod attribute like so.

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

This should enable you to access the Session object.